# ¿Cómo traducir “keep a lot of irons in the fire”?

Tags: traducción, modismos

Estoy traduciendo un texto en inglés donde aparece la frase *“kept a lot of irons in the fire”*. El significado de la frase idiomática *irons in the fire* es, según el Wiktionary,

> Tasks in progress; involvement in ongoing projects.

o sea, tareas en proceso o involucramiento en proyectos en marcha. Se refiere a la costumbre de los herreros de trabajar con varias piezas a la vez (sin sacarlas del fuego de la forja, se entiende). Se puede usar con connotación positiva o negativa. Me gustaría saber si hay un equivalente en castellano que mantenga este tono coloquial o figurativo. (El contexto es el de un escritor freelance que, aun cuando acaba de triunfar con una novela exitosa, no deja de trabajar en otras cosas, literarias y no.)

Comment: Esta frase para mí tiene una connotación casi siempre positiva, en contraste a otras con significado parecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Tener varios frentes abiertos"** podría ser una.
También se usa a veces **"tener mucha plancha"** cuando tenemos muchas tareas pendientes en casa.
**"Tener algo en el horno"** se usa cuando se quiere decir que algo está en preparación, por ejemplo una novela (relacionada con la consabida *"recién salida del horno"* cuando por fin se publica). Podrías decir ***"tiene varios libros en el horno"***.

Si se me ocurre alguna más certera, la pondré.

Comment: Me gustó eso de "tener varios X en el horno" porque conserva algo de la imagen de la forja.

Answer (score 2):

La traducción formal podría ser "en curso" o "en ciernes".

Como equivalente coloquial, se me ocurre "tenía muchas cosas / muchos trabajos **entre manos**."

Answer (score 0):

Tener **cosas pendientes**.  Ejemplo:

> Tengo varias cosas pendientes pero dentro de 15 dias ya voy a tener tiempo para etc.

pendiente: 3. [juicio, caso, pedido] pending *aún tenemos un par de asuntos pendientes | we still have a couple of matters pending.*

Técnicamente *proyectos* sería correcto, pero en la práctica, es más fácil y común decir *cosas*.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sencilla de decirlo es "estoy muy atareado" o, de manera más coloquial, en México se usa "estoy que no me doy abasto" lo cual hace referencia a que el tiempo apenas alcanza para trabajar en todos los projectos que están en curso.